# Define a "square" command

Tags: macros, pstricks

I try to define the following command, for drawing a square in pstricks:

```
\newcommand{\square}[4] {
  \rput(#1,#2){\psframe[linecolor=#4](0,0)(#3,#3)}
}
```

I use it like this (for drawing a red square with a corner at (1,1) and a side-length of 3):

```
\square(1,1,3,red)
```

And get the following errors:

```
Package xcolor error: Undefined color '1'.
Missing number, treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Additionally, if there is a simpler way to write this square command, I will be happy to learn..)

Comment: Try `\square{1}{1}{3}{red}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the PSTricks object definition. Then you have the same syntax for options and star versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatletter
\def\square{\pst@object{square}}% reads star and options and continues with \square@i
\def\square@i(#1,#2)#3{{\use@par\solid@star\psframe[origin={#1,#2}](#3,#3)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
\square(1,1){3}
\square[linecolor=red](0,0.5){2}
\square[linecolor=blue,fillcolor=red!40,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5](2,0){2}
\square*[linecolor=cyan,opacity=0.4](0,2){2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is much better than my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Of course calling:

```
\square(1,1,3,red)
```

can not work if you define:

```
\newcommand{\square}[4] {
  \rput(#1,#2){\psframe[linecolor=#4](0,0)(#3,#3)}
}
```

because LaTeX handles arguments differently from other programming languages. You should call:

```
\square{1}{1}{3}{red}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand{\square}[4] {
  \rput(#1,#2){\psframe[linecolor=#4](0,0)(#3,#3)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)
\square{1}{1}{3}{red}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If you really wish to use:

```
\square(1,1,3,red)
```

you have the possibility, but you should modify the definition with the following:

```
\def\square(#1,#2,#3,#4){
  \rput(#1,#2){\psframe[linecolor=#4](0,0)(#3,#3)}
}
```

The example becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\square(#1,#2,#3,#4){
  \rput(#1,#2){\psframe[linecolor=#4](0,0)(#3,#3)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)
\square(1,1,3,red)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for advertising the existence of the new macro, `\reversepath` that was introduced in the late of 2013.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\def\RightWing{\psline(0,.5)(.5,.5)(.5,-.5)(0,-.5)}
\def\square(#1,#2)#3#4{%
    \pscustom[linecolor=#4,origin={#1,#2}]
    {
        \scale{#3 #3}
        \RightWing
        \reversepath
        \scale{-1 1}
        \RightWing
        \closepath
    }
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \square(0,0){3}{red}
    \square(3,3){2}{blue}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]